# git-p4 and config git-p4.largeFileExtensions

Tags: git, git-p4, git-lfs

I am attempting to convert a Perforce repository to a git one, using `git-p4` (using git for Windows). I have many images, and would like to use LFS for them. However, I can't seem to get the `git-p4.largeFileExtensions` config setting to work properly with multiple extensions. If I execute the following:

```
git config       git-p4.largeFileSystem     GitLFS
git config       git-p4.largeFileExtensions png
git config --add git-p4.largeFileExtensions jpg
git p4 clone --verbose //depot/project@all .
```

I get (if I use more than two, all pairs report a similar warning):

```
WARNING: These git config values clash:
  git config "git-p4.largefileextensions" = "png"
  git config "git-p4.largefileextensions" = "jpg"
```

The `.git/config` file is what I would expect, a multivalue entry for largeFileExtensions:

```
[git-p4]
        largeFileSystem = GitLFS
        largeFileExtensions = png
        largeFileExtensions = jpg
```

The however `.gitattributes` file created looks like:

```
#
# Git LFS (see https://git-lfs.github.com/)
#
*.png
jpg filter=lfs -text
```

Am I doing something wrong, or does the `largeFileExtensions` attribute formatted differently?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This appears to be a problem with git for Windows outputting incorrect line endings for Windows. If I run:

```
git config --get-all git-p4.largeFileExtensions
```

it will give me:

```
png\r
jpg\r
```

In the `git-p4.py` script, it uses `split(os.linesep)` to split the output from the command line. On Windows, `os.linesep = '\r\n'`, and thus the lines don't get split. If I change the script to use `splitlines()` instead, then it still gives the clash warnings, however, it seems as though the tracking is now correct.

Answer (score 1):

Note that, in addition of `git-p4.largeFileExtensions`, "`git p4`" also used to ignore `lfs.storage` configuration variable, which has been corrected with Git 2.25 (Q1 2020).

See [commit ea94b16](https://github.com/git/git/commit/ea94b16fb832d6e0bc2fb8761fd4a89555002bcc) (11 Dec 2019) by [r.burenkov (`panzercheg`)](https://github.com/panzercheg).
<sup>(Merged by [Junio C Hamano -- `gitster` --](https://github.com/gitster) in [commit 20aa6d8](https://github.com/git/git/commit/20aa6d88b7494bf922abce7142485223731e5323), 25 Dec 2019)</sup>

> ### [`git-p4`](https://github.com/git/git/commit/ea94b16fb832d6e0bc2fb8761fd4a89555002bcc): honor lfs.storage configuration variable
>
> <sup>Signed-off-by: r.burenkov</sup>
>
> "git lfs" allows users to specify the custom storage location with the configuration variable `lfs.storage`, but when interacting with GitLFS pointers, "git p4" always uses the hardcoded default that is the `.git/lfs/` directory, without paying attention to the configuration.
>
> Use the value configured in `lfs.storage`, if exists, as all the "git" operations do, for consistency.

---

And, before Git 2.43 (Q4 2023), `git p4` tried to store symlinks to LFS when told, but has been fixed not to do so, because it does not make sense.

See [commit 10c89a0](https://github.com/git/git/commit/10c89a02b046e67c861f226064180c4f978a9cc3) (18 Oct 2023) by [Matthew McClain (`MatthewMcClain17`)](https://github.com/MatthewMcClain17).
<sup>(Merged by [Junio C Hamano -- `gitster` --](https://github.com/gitster) in [commit 9030f85](https://github.com/git/git/commit/9030f85730b47f421e2b9f75c6c6560c62d5d481), 30 Oct 2023)</sup>

> ### [`10c89a02b0`](https://github.com/git/git/commit/10c89a02b046e67c861f226064180c4f978a9cc3):git-p4 shouldn't attempt to store symlinks in LFS
>
> <sup>Signed-off-by: Matthew McClain</sup>

> `git-p4.py` would attempt to put a symlink in LFS if its file extension matched `git-p4.largeFileExtensions`.
>
> Git LFS doesn't store symlinks because smudge/clean filters don't handle symlinks.
> They never get passed to the filter process nor the smudge/clean filters, nor could that occur without a change to the protocol or command-line interface.
> Unless Git learned how to send them to the filters, Git LFS would have a hard time using them in any useful way.
>
> Git LFS's goal is to move large files out of the repository history, and symlinks are functionally limited to 4 KiB or a similar size on most systems.

Answer (score 0):

I used `git p4` to migrate an existing Perforce depot and workspaces to a new git repo and I used `git lfs migrate` to move the large files elsewhere. Check a great github tutorial [here](https://github.com/git-lfs/git-lfs/wiki/Tutorial).

To list the files and its sizes:

```
git lfs migrate info --everything
```

To remove all .bin files in the history (rewrites commits) and set the LFS config:

```
git lfs migrate import --include="*.bin"
```

Before you git push the new repo to remote, you can also change GitHub LFS server url to another [implementation](https://github.com/git-lfs/git-lfs/wiki/Implementations). Check the LFS config by executing `git lfs env` and change the url by `git config -f .lfsconfig lfs.url https://your.server.com/info/lfs`.